# Progressive number into "insert into select"

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've a stored procedure in which I do more then one "insert into select" into the same table. Within the stored procedure i want to add a progressive number to each record that I add, starting from 1.
To make it clear, in the first "insert into select" of my stored I add 5 records to my table, and they will have in a column the progressive number (1,2...,5), in the second "insert into select" I add other 5 records and they should have the progressive (6,7...10)

p.s. the solution shoudln't be heavy,  I could make a select of the max current id, and make the difference with the max id at the start of the stored, but this would slow too much my procedure

Comment: Add an `Identity` column to the table you're selecting into.

Comment: Make that column `identity(1,1)` and it will increment for each record inserted into the table

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simplest solution is to use an `identity` column in the table you are creating.  However, this does not guarantee a sequence, but in practice it would be the right idea.

An alternative is to use `row_number()` to assign a sequence:

```
insert into . . .
    select @offset +  row_number() over (order by (select NULL)), . . 
    . . .;
```

This has additional overhead, because you have to keep track of `@offset` so the value is correct.  This method is robust, in the sense that another thread adding rows into the table will not affect your particular sequence numbers.

My preference is the first solution.  If you then need to get sequence numbers with no gap, you can use `row_number()` when you query.

Comment: Also note that the second option isn't safe - it can cause broken sequences and duplicate IDs. If you do this, you need to use serializable transaction isolation.

Comment: But the progressive number have to start from 1 for each time i start my procedure, can I make this happen with the identity column? 
Otherwise the solution of the row_number() looks great, only question, is there  an easy way to get the last row_number() after an insert into select?

Comment: @Sophie  . . . An `identity` column will not start over.  You can use the `OUTPUT` clause to capture the data put into the table.  Then it is a simple query on that.